# Copying range to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have come across some code to copy a range to a new workbook, but I'm not sure why it works.

```
Worksheets("Short Form").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

How does this copy the worksheet 'Short Form' to a new workbook when all that the code says is assign the active workbook to the reference 'wb'? It doesn't even employ the .add method. Right now I want to paste values only to this new workbook, but not quite sure how to do so because I don't understand this block of code.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more code? Because all you have now (if i'm correct) is copy worksheet "Short Form" and set wb as the Active Workbook.

Comment: By default Worksheet.Copy copies the worksheet to a new workbook. So this code is copying an entire worksheet and then setting wb as a reference to the newly created workbook.

Comment: Worksheets("name").Copy  -doesnt mean COPY ONLY

see [DOCS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835605.aspx)

Comment: haha, that's just it t.thielemans, that's the code! All it's missing is the subroutine name and end sub codes, and it works.

Comment: ohhhh, thank you Ross and mehow.

Comment: Oh lol didn't know that. Learnt something new aswell ^^

Comment: @mehow in the `OP` code it **does** mean copy only...but yes there are additional argumenst that can be used to do other things

Comment: @J.Waters two quite extensive answers have been thought through and provided - do you have any comments?

Comment: I thank you whytheq and david Zemens for your answers, But at the time (some 25 days ago) mehow's answer was quite sufficient. My job doesn't always involve coding and so I had no reason to login to the site again, and I am sorry. But you have put forward two examples I can use for reference for functionality and good programming practice. I'm sorry someone felt  the need to downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - as the following manual steps are the same as your code snippet:

1.Open a blank workbook
2.Press record macro
3.Right click the Sheet1 workbook tab
4.Select "Move or Copy"
5.In the "To book" combo select (new book)
6.Check the "Create a copy" box so that the window now looks like this:
[image] 
7.Stop the recorder
8.Go and find your recorded code ...and voila....mine looks like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
End Sub
```

Your code is the same as what these manual steps describe.

---

You must have a line  `Dim wb as workbook` somewhere or it would not run.

This line `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` will then make the object `wb` equal to the new workbook that you have copied into, as it is active, so you can do further operations on it. You can easily switch the workbook that wb is pointed at:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim wb As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox wb.Name
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox wb.Name

End Sub
```

**BUT**
In my production code I generally never use `Set x To ActiveWorkbook` I always name the workbook and then use `Set x To Workbooks("DefiniteName")`

---

**WITHOUT USING CLIPBOARD**
If you want to avoid using the clip board then the following example shows how to move values-only data without using paste:

```
Sub WithoutPastespecial()


Dim firstRange As Range
Set firstRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Short Form").Range("S4:S2000") 'can change S4:S2000 to the range you want to copy

Dim newBk As Workbook
Dim secondRange As Range
Set newBk = Workbooks.Add
Set secondRange = newBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

With firstRange
      Set secondRange = secondRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
End With
secondRange.Value = firstRange.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this is not copying a `Range` rather the entire worskheet :)

If you use the method:

`Worksheets("Short Form").Cells.Copy`

Then you will copy only the cells, not the entire worksheet, and this method will NOT create a new workbook. You can tell it to add a workbook when necessary.

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNew()
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook  'It is a good idea to explicitly control workbooks using either a defined variable like "wb" or the "ThisWorkbook" object, instead of using "ActiveWorkbook" or referring to files by name.

Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb.Sheets("Short Form").Cells.Copy


'Add a new workbook for the values:
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

wbNew.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: This line of code `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` is pointless ...all you are doing is shortening `ThisWorkbook` to this `wb`. You save on some typing but then later on in the code things become much less readable as it says wb and the reader of the code might not realise it refers to `ThisWorkbook`. Can you provide a definite example of why this is "always a good idea"?

Comment: No you're absolutely correct. Using `wb` in lieu of `ThisWorkbook` is a personal preference. What I meant was, whenever working with multiple workbooks, it is a good idea to use variables for each (or if you prefer, `ThisWorkbook` and one workbook variable) rather than referring to them explicitly (by name) or by `ActiveWorkbook` which the macro recorder will generate.  However, I find that using a `wb` instead of `ThisWorkbook` makes slightly more reusable. Perhaps you want to use this in an application, an XLAM add-in file, etc. Then you need only change the line which `Set wb = ...`.

Comment: ...ok no worries - agreed; I'd certainly make a reference to `Workbooks("this has a really long name")` and agree that it is good practice to pop that into an object variable such as `wb`